# Update d3.js data with setInterval, not xAxis labels update

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I have done an D3JS example similar to [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8) but instead of updating data with a button, update it with a setInterval as I am receiving a different JSON each 15 minutes.

For that reason, I am looking each 15seconds for a new JSON. I have done a simple example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iblasi/attoeaqd/) on JSFidle that uses setInterval and update the information if it exists. The function for update the data is "D3JS_Update_fig":

```
// Update figure data (http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8)
function D3JS_Update_fig(timestamp) {

    //var timestamp = json.meta.timestamp;
    //var dataA = json.data.dataA;
    //var dataB = json.data.dataB;
    var dataA_line = d3.select("#dataA").data()[0];
    var dataB_line = d3.select("#dataB").data()[0];


    var t_ini = new Date(new Number(parseInt((timestamp)*1000)));
    var t_fin = new Date(new Number(parseInt((timestamp + 3600)*1000)));

    D3JS_xscale = d3.time.scale().domain([t_ini,t_fin]).range([0,SAFIP_width]);
    D3JS_lower_x_Axis.scale(D3JS_xscale);

    dataA_line.forEach(function(array,index){
      array.value = Math.sin(parseInt((timestamp + index*60)*1000));
      array.time = new Date(new Number(parseInt((timestamp + index*60)*1000)));
    });
    dataB_line.forEach(function(array,index){
      array.value = Math.sin(parseInt((timestamp + index*60)*1000))*0.5;
      array.time = new Date(new Number(parseInt((timestamp + index*60)*1000)));
    });

    // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
    d3.select("#dataA.line")
          .transition()
          .duration(750)
          .attr("d", D3JS_line_function(dataA_line));

    d3.select("#dataB.line")
          .transition()
          .duration(750)
          .attr("d", D3JS_line_function(dataB_line));

    d3.select(".x.axis")
          .transition()
          .duration(750)
          .call(D3JS_lower_x_Axis);
}
```

The data and time variables are correctly updated and the plotted lines are updating as expected. As you can see on the following image, the data corresponds to each 15 minute interval (I have used a Math.sin function with timestamp to simulate a random with seed the data to be coherent on each update).

[image: D3JS setInterval]

The problem is that although the lines (y-value and time) are correctly updated, the xAxis tick labels are not updated. On the example I mention previously ([here](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8)), the labels are updated and I am doing something similar to that, so I do not find the problem on the code.

Maybe a problem on variable names? Maybe a wrong ID of jQuery? I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that mostly everything was correct but it was also necessary to update on X axis the following features on the following way:

```
d3.select("#D3JS_graph_plot #lower_x_axis")
  .transition()
  .duration(750)
  .call(D3JS_lower_x_Axis)
  .selectAll("text")
     .style("text-anchor", "end")
     .attr("dx", "-0.3em")
     .attr("dy", "0.9em")
     .attr("transform", function(d) {
         return "rotate(-35)"
  });
```

where the #lower_x_axis is the id attribute of svg lower x Axis (line 124 on JSfiddle example) and #D3JS_graph_plot is the id of the graph called "selector" on the example.